# Calculating work hours in oracle

Tags: oracle, datetime, date-difference

I have a table which stores the date and time a task starts and ends and based on the number of hours worked payment will be made in the month end.

The task duration differs from 2 hours to 3 days.

The working time of one day is 8 hours.

I need to find the No. of hours worked in a day.

The data stored in my db is like this

```
sno | start_time            |  end_time           |
---------------------------------------------------
1   |06-10-2016 09:30:00    | 06-10-2016 17:00:00 |
2   |12-10-2016 08:00:00    | 15-10-2016 13:00:00 |
```

I need to get the total hours worked which is 36:30 hours and convert it to days as 5 days.

When I run my query I was able to get this output.

```
sno | start_time         |   end_time          |  time_diff         |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
1   |06-10-2016 09:30:00 |  06-10-2016 17:00:00| +00 07:30:00.000000|
2   |12-10-2016 08:00:00 |  15-10-2016 13:00:00| +03 05:00:00.000000|
```

My query:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT sno,  start_time,end_time, 
TO_TIMESTAMP (end_time,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') - TO_TIMESTAMP (start_time,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS time_diff
FROM employee WHERE  TO_CHAR((start_time),'MM-YYYY')='10-2016' AND emp_no ='18754';
```

My desired output is

```
|Total_no_days|
---------------
|  5          |
```

But I am unaware of how to proceed now.
Some one please help.

Comment: I don't understand why it will become 5 days.  Do you simply means for every record, round up to nearest day if "time" in time_diff is less than 8:00:00?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just subtract dates and multiply by 24 this will give you hours. Then divide by 8 and you get your working days.

```
with d as (select sysdate end_date, sysdate - 2.4 as start_date from dual)
select (end_date - start_date) * 24 / 8 from d;
```

In fact you can multiply by 3:

```
with d as (select sysdate end_date, sysdate - 2.4 as start_date from dual)
select (end_date - start_date) * 3 from d;
```

So in your case you can use `to_date` instead of `to_timestamp` and just subtract values.

Your query is:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT sno,  start_time,end_time, 
(TO_DATE (end_time,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') - TO_DATE(start_time,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')) * 3 AS time_diff_work_days
FROM employee WHERE  TO_CHAR((start_time),'MM-YYYY')='10-2016' AND emp_no ='18754';
```

Comment: What does that `2.4` refer to and why do we use the `sysdate` here?

Comment: I use `sysdate just as example. It is equivalent to `to_date('18112016 10:00','ddmmyyyy hh:mm')` and `to_date('16112016 5:00','ddmmyyyy hh:mm')`. @TonyRoczz I've edited answer and added your query returning diff in working days

Comment: For me the start and end date i get from a table here where do i give the table and the employee no?

Answer (score 0):

Since the `start_time` and `end_time` appear to be of the `DATE` type you can just do:

```
SELECT  SUM( end_time - start_time ) * 24 / 8 AS Total_no_days
FROM    employee
WHERE   start_time >= DATE '2016-10-01'
AND     start_time <  DATE '2016-11-01'
AND     emp_no ='18754';
```